# GeoJSON item considered a JSON instead of a string

Tags: qgis, json, string

Some items in a geojson file work correctly in a linux environment but not in a windows environment. The following structure: `{ "name": "1", "key": { "start": "2000-01-01", "end": "2023-11-30" }`, "area": 1.0 }, works perfectly on linux and looks like:

[image: Attribute table Linux]

[image: Fields Linux]

But when the same file is used in QGIS in a windows environment, this happens:

[image: Attribute table Windows]

[image: Fields Windows]

The key column is considered as a `Map` instead of a text. I have no idea how I can change this setting, I'm not sure if it's the software or the environment and even exporting this file generates errors.

GeoJSON

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "name": "file",
  "crs": {
    "type": "name",
    "properties": {
      "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"
    }
  },
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "1",
        "key": {
          "start": "2000-01-01",
          "end": "2023-11-30"
        },
        "area": 1
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                ...
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Same QGIS version?

Comment: How does it look *exactly* in the GeoJSON file? Your formatting in the question is half missing and ambiguous.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Tested on the same and different versions of qgis (I tested the latest version and ltr). I've added the geojson structure, it's actually a very simple file.

Comment: The GDAL version may also make a difference. See also the open option ARRAY_AS_STRING https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html#open-options.

Comment: @user30184 tried both things,different versions of GDAL.The only thing that actually helped a bit was the function "to_json", but doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Do I understand it right that you want json content to appear as a string?

Comment: @user30184 yes, exactly. Technically using this function I'm transforming it into a JSON string.

Comment: Odd, I think that YES/NO should show different results with your data when running `ogrinfo jsonjson.json -al  --config OGR_GEOJSON_ARRAY_AS_STRING YES`.

Comment: I was wrong, OGR_GEOJSON_ARRAY_AS_STRING deals naturally only with arrays and it will not help in your case. Do you have the same QGIS versions on both machines? It looks like  converting such JSON string into a special JSON type attribute is intentional and not a bug.

Comment: @user30184 I agree that this is intentional and not a bug and that's why it makes sense that in some way this can be configured. Yes, the QGIS versions are the same

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it even better than the previous "perfect" behavior now when data are interpreted to mean a "map" instead of an unstructured string? QGIS knows that attribute contains elements and it also allows to edit them separately in the form view. When the data are saved back into GeoJSON the JSON structure remains the same.

[image]

Export failed until I checked the "Use Key/Value" option here:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem because I still need it to be a string in different parts of the process and QGIS is just one of them. Also, this raises a bigger question of where this configuration is being done

Comment: It seems to me that the current QGIS version does not have such configuration option. You never told which program versions you have on Linux and on Windows. But I have a workaround for you and I will write it as another answer soon.

Comment: I've tested different version, but currently I'm using the LTR 3.28.15 Firenze

Answer (score 1):

It seems that QGIS has a special handling for JSON structures in GeoJSON files. However, it is possible to convert data into some other format than GeoJSON for bypassing the GeoJSON specialities.

When GDAL opens the test json file it finds that the "key" attribute contains JSON.

```
ogrinfo -al jsonjson.json
...
OGRFeature(file):0
  name (String) = 1
  key (String(JSON)) = { "start": "2000-01-01", "end": "2023-11-30" }
  area (Integer) = 1
  MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
```

However, it is possible to cast the String(JSON) type into string with the GDAL OGRSQL dialect (notice that the convenient `EXCLUDE` SQL keyword is new and requires the newest GDAL but cast works also with older versions).

```
ogrinfo jsonjson.json -sql "select * EXCLUDE (key), cast(key as character) from file" jsonjson.json
...
OGRFeature(file):0
  name (String) = 1
  area (Integer) = 1
  key (String) = { "start": "2000-01-01", "end": "2023-11-30" }
  MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY
```

With this option it is possible to convert JSON field into string and save the result into a GeoPackage file.

```
ogr2ogr -f gpkg -sql "select * EXCLUDE (key), cast(key as character(100)) from file" jsonjson.gpkg jsonjson.json
```

The new GeoPackage file opens into QGIS as desired:

[image]

[image]